# passing python modules on HDFS through livy

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, python-module, livy

On the */user/usr1/* path in HDFS, I placed two scripts *pySparkScript.py* and *relatedModule.py*. *relatedModule.py* is a python module which will be imported into *pySparkScript.py*.

I can run the scripts with `spark-submit pySparkScript.py`

However, I need to run these scripts through Livy. Normally, I run single scripts successfully as the following:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"file": "/user/usr1/pySparkScript.py"}' livyNodeAddress/batches
```

However, when I run the above code, as soon as it gets to `import relatedModule.py` it fails. I realize I should give the path to the *relatedModule* also in the parameters of Livy. I tried the following option:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"file": "/user/usr1/pySparkScript.py", "files": ["/user/usr1/relatedModule.py"]}' livyNodeAddress/batches
```

**How should I pass both files to Livy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `pyFiles` property.
Please refer [Livy REST API docs](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html).